# automatization of numerical derivation

Tags: numerical-methods, derivatives

I would like to know if there is an automized or fast way to numerically derivate a large number of tab-delimited files (derived from the program kaleidagraph) and to automatically extract some key information from it?

It is a longitudinal growth study and i'm currently testing some non-parametric models. I have a tab delimited file with time in column 1 and size in column 2.

I wonder if there is a program that for every file can give me the second derivate numerically (that would be column 3) and the following parameters. 
 - the maximum growth obtained (end of the curve)
 - the time T2 when velocity V2 is maximum and the corresponding velocity and size 
 - the time T1 when velocity is minimum and T1

Since i have over a 1000 files and more i wondered if some tool or program could do the trick for me.

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Niels

Comment: Sounds like something that would be perfect for [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) (or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)) or [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)/[SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) if you like. This could even be done in a spreadsheet program like Excel, I imagine.

Comment: In Matlab you'll want to used the [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function to compute second order finite differences. Taking derivatives (especially second derivatives) will amplify any noise in the data. You can attempt to mitigate this by instead applying a smoothing derivative filter. [Savitzky-Golay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky–Golay_smoothing_filter) is a popular technique for this and Matlab has a builtin function for it: [`sgolay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html).